# Ruby Multi-Threading Sql (in test environment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I have a problem in my tests running some SQL queries in different threads. I expect that running simple select and counts in SQL would return the same results, but if I run these methods in threads (`process_new_followers` and `process_lost_followers`) they return different results.

Here is the (basic) code:

```
def compute_followers
  followers = Follower.where({ user_id: user_id, is_following: true }).count # => returns 10 always

  calculate_differences
  thread1 = Thread.new { process_new_followers }
  thread2 = Thread.new { process_lost_followers }
  thread1.join
  thread2.join

end

def process_new_followers
  puts Follower.where({ user_id: user_id, is_following: true }).count # => returns 0 if threaded and 10 if not
  ... I commented out this code so it only prints the count and nothing changes, so no db changes are happening in this method
end

def process_lost_followers
  puts Follower.where({ user_id: user_id, is_following: true }).count # => returns 0 if threaded and 10 if not
  ... I commented out this code so it only prints the count and nothing changes, so no db changes are happening in this method
end
```

Why would the threading effect this SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is in a Rails app using ActiveRecord, Rails will rollback all transactions in it's test suite. Since you're stepping outside of it in a thread, the transaction has most likely already rolled back, which would explain why you're seeing 0 count in threaded and 10 in non-threaded call.